# Backward calls and onActivityResult() not calling in Fragment but calls in activity

Tags: android

I have A activity. This contain 4 Fragments. I created separated Fragment class in other packages. so A activity contain 4 Fragments. one of them is B fragment. Now B Fragment calls to Activity C by startActivityForResult. so i writes the method onActivityResult in B Fragment. But same method is also in Activity A which is most important and can't be remove. Now when I came back from C -- > B then onActivityResult is not calling but activity A's onActivityResult calls. so how can i call to this method in (B)fragment too. so i can change the data by calling it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
super.onActivityResult();
```

in your Activities onActivityResult() to pass the Callback to your Fragment.